# Dark (mature) female comics character who burns rapists' penises with her heat-based powers

Tags: marvel, dc, comics, character-identification

I remember seeing this video on YouTube, I think it was a Top 10 Nerd video where this female character would find rapists and burn their dicks off with her heat-based power.

Does anyone know who that is? It keeps coming to my mind but for the life of me, I don't know her name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be Cinder from DC Comics' *Titans: Villains For Hire* (2011).

From [Comic Book Resources](https://www.cbr.com/things-that-turned-out-bad-did-she-really-just-kill-that-guy-with-her-you-know-what/):

> The basics for Cinder is that she was an Italian woman from a well-to-do family that was molested by her uncle. So **she then hunts down sex offenders and kill them.** When we first meet her, **she's killing a sex offender by burning him alive (her power is to turn into walking molten lava) while having sex, so she uses her vagina to attack the guy...** [...]
>
> So Deathstroke offers her a deal - join his new team and he'll help her hunt down well-protected sex offenders...

[image: (safe for work) short, black-haired young woman burning a guy's penis while having sex with him]

---

Found with the Google query `female comics character hunt sex offenders`.